# Wi-Fi not remembered by Windows 10 after reboot

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

We recently bought a small form factor desktop PC for one of our staff. Unfortunately it doesn't remember the default home Wi-Fi network after a reboot.

Normally we distribute laptops to staff which they can use at home, but in this case we wanted to place a small desktop PC with someone at home. All our laptops are member of a Windows domain and so is this desktop PC. When we test with a laptop the Wi-Fi *is* remembered after a reboot, but when we use the Desktop PC it is not.

We've tried a bunch of things:

- updating/reinstalling wireless drivers
- forgetting the wifi name and adding it again
- uninstalling OEM wireless tools (Intel PROset)
- bare (non-OEM) Windows-10 installation
- disabling device power management
- add fMinimizeConnections registry key
- run the window 'Network Troubleshooter'
- disable Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
- turn off Windows Network Connectivity Status Indicator active tests
- turn off Fast Startup feature
- change the security permissions of Wlansvc directory
- remove specific files from Wlansvc directory
- manually create a new wireless network connection
- Perform DISM and SFC scan
- disable: 'Minimize the number of simultaneous connections to the Internet or a Windows Domain'

...all to no avail.

Does Windows 10 (v1903) treat Desktop PCs differently than Laptops? Can we override such behaviour using group policy perhaps? Has anyone seen similar behaviour?

Comment: “Does Windows 10 (v1903) treat Desktop PCs differently than Laptops?“ - This absolutely is not the case.  Windows doesn’t know what’s a “Desktop” and what’s a “Laptop”.

Comment: Windows 10 most certainly optimizes itself based on platform, but I doubt that is related to this issue. Have you reviewed the event log for related events? Especially during reboot.

Comment: We had the same problem with a model.We tried everything... adding a noname wifi usb card worked instantly. So we resend the model and got a new one from the reseller.

Comment: You did everything possible and exhausted all the possibilities, except, as noted above, returning the device.

Comment: @Ramhound The only thing I can see that Windows may use to differentiate between a laptop and a desktop computer is the presence of a battery, but you're right, it shouldn't know what kind of device it actually is.

Comment: @Appleoddity Event logs were not kept, but this has been such a rare case that I completely forgot about that.

Comment: @Vindic We ended up returning the unit and requested a refund before we could try an external WiFi card. Ok, thanks for the feedback all. I'm a bit more confident I tried all the obvious things..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has returned the device and the problem cannot be furthered diagnosed thus any answer submitted could not be verified as being correct or incorrect.

Comment: @Ramhound Please don't make the question go away entirely because it may help someone else see what 'solutions' don't work in this case. I would have been very happy to come across a post like this during my research into the problem.

Comment: @captcha - If no answer is submitted then this question will be eventually automatically deleted anyways.  As with any non-binding vote I can cast, it will require additional community users, before this question will be closed.  **I will absolutely not retract my close vote not should I be blamed if the community agrees with me**

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does optimize for different hardware types.

It does not, however, change how it manages wireless networks for all of this optimization.

If the computer has a wireless network card, it will manage wireless networks the same way by default.

Because you are experiencing differently, there is something else, besides the OS' default function itself, that is causing this.

It could be the device, it could be the driver (less likely), or it could be an odd bug elsewhere in the system.

Right now the best option is to replace the hardware as others have already suggested in comments. That is the correct course of action given the information you've given us so far.

Comment: Yeah, we sent the unit back and got a refund.

Comment: Then please mark this as the correct answer to help others with similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Has anybody tried this?

Disable Intel PROSet/Wireless WiFi Connection Utility

https://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-windows-10-wont-remember-saved-wifi-password/

Maybe Method #3

Method 3: Forget Wifi Network

Comment: Tried those. Removing the Intel PROSet tools didn't fix it, nor did 'forget network'. I even installed Windows from a plan (non-OEM) installation DVD without any 3rd party wireless tools and it still didn't work.